# C# select from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to make a extra control in my C# application if the record exist.

I have got the following code - but it keeps returning a result of -1 even though the record does exist in the SQL Server database.

Can someone help me with this? I have added --> for where it went wrong

```
private void btnVerwijderen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (autonrTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Waarschuwing u kunt geen auto verwijderen indien er GEEN autonr is ingevuld");
    }
    else
    {
    --> SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-RSEBNR7;Initial Catalog=AudiDealer;Integrated Security=True");
    --> string check = "SELECT autonr FROM auto WHERE autonr =@autonr";

    --> SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(check, con);
    --> command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@autonr", autonrTextBox.Text);

        con.Open();
        int auto = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

--> X - 1   MessageBox.Show(auto.ToString());

        if (auto > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM auto WHERE autonr =" + autonrTextBox.Text, con))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (SystemException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Het opgegeven autonr komt niet voor in de database. controleer deze.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try casting your `autonrTextBox.Text` to an int when setting it as the parameter value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ExecuteNonQuery()` method doesn't work like you think it does. The return value for this method is the number of rows changed, not anything from the result set. SELECT queries don't change rows, so -1 is the expected result. 0 rows would imply a WHERE clause that matched no rows in an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT. -1 is used to indicate a different situation... either a statement that doesn't change rows or a rollback. Check the remarks section in the [documentation for the method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

You want to use the `ExecuteScalar()` method instead.

```
int auto = -1;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-RSEBNR7;Initial Catalog=AudiDealer;Integrated Security=True"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT autonr FROM auto WHERE autonr =@autonr", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@autonr", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(autonrTextBox.Text);
    con.Open();
    auto = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Finally... why check before deleting? This is just wasteful. Just issue the DELETE statement. There's no need to do a SELECT first. Your try/catch and the if() checks already handle situations where the record doesn't exist just fine.

```
int autonr = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(autonrTextBox.Text, autonr))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Waarschuwing u kunt geen auto verwijderen indien er GEEN autonr is ingevuld");
}
else
{
    try 
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-RSEBNR7;Initial Catalog=AudiDealer;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM auto WHERE autonr = @autonr;", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@autonr", SqlDbType.Int).Value = autonr;
            con.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result <= 0)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Het opgegeven autonr komt niet voor in de database. controleer deze.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: how can i do this for a string type?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `command1.ExecuteNonQuery()` which returns the number of modified rows. Your query doesn't modify anything but only reads data from database, so the return value will be always -1.

So use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead - it will return your `autonr` value. Just remember to check it for `null` and cast it to correct type:

```
int auto = 0;
object result = command1.ExecuteScalar();
if (result != null)
    auto = (int)result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use ExecuteScalar, ExecuteNonQuery will not return the result.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery return only the the row that was change/add/remove
if you want to know how many you have use in the query Count and get the rows'number

```
SELECT Count(*) as CountAutonr  FROM auto WHERE autonr =@autonr
```

and then you will get the from the  CountAutonr   the number of Rows

Answer (score 0):

There're many things wrong in that piece of code, I really recommend you to encapsulate those database queries inside a business class that will connect to the database, retrieve the data and return as a DAO object... but that won't answer your question.

The issue is in the select command execution, `ExecuteNonQuery` is meant for executing UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements, returning the number of affected rows:

```
con.Open();
**int auto = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();**
con.Close();
```

You must use `ExecuteReader` method to retrieve the SELECT results as explained in the following article:

[Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)